# Is there parking near Kirby Cove, San Francisco, USA?

Tags: automobiles, san-francisco-bay-area

I would like to get a nice view of the Golden Gate Bridge from Kirby Cove. I am wondering though if there is any sort of parking area near Kirby Cove. I am also wondering if it is jam packed for parking in July.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fairly small amount of parking in two clusters along [Conzelman Road](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Battery+Kirby/@37.8293628,-122.485699,249m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0xbcbf06c7b5119c45!2sKIRBY+COVE+CAMPGROUND!8m2!3d37.8279783!4d-122.490308!3m4!1s0x0:0xc8375b99bc84e3f8!8m2!3d37.8273575!4d-122.4901503) near the visa point. From there you can hike down the trail all the way to Kirby Cove (be advised, especially for the way back up, that it's a fairly steep trail).

It may be somewhat rather, but some people only stop to take a few pictures, so if the spaces are full, you could wait a bit and take the space of someone leaving. Failing that, there's a [bigger lot](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Battery+Kirby/@37.8321139,-122.4824283,344m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0xbcbf06c7b5119c45!2sKIRBY+COVE+CAMPGROUND!8m2!3d37.8279783!4d-122.490308!3m4!1s0x0:0xc8375b99bc84e3f8!8m2!3d37.8273575!4d-122.4901503) just after the underpass and you could walk from there. There is also more parking further down Conzelman Road, such as at [the traffic circle](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Battery+Kirby/@37.8334554,-122.4949675,413m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0xbcbf06c7b5119c45!2sKIRBY+COVE+CAMPGROUND!8m2!3d37.8279783!4d-122.490308!3m4!1s0x0:0xc8375b99bc84e3f8!8m2!3d37.8273575!4d-122.4901503) or [Hawk Hill](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Battery+Kirby/@37.8273338,-122.4995366,211m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0xbcbf06c7b5119c45!2sKIRBY+COVE+CAMPGROUND!8m2!3d37.8279783!4d-122.490308!3m4!1s0x0:0xc8375b99bc84e3f8!8m2!3d37.8273575!4d-122.4901503). Visiting outside of peak visiting periods, especially weekends during the summer, may help avoid crowds and traffic.

Once you're done there, I'd also recommend going a bit further and checking out [the lighthouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_Bonita_Lighthouse) at lovely Point Bonita. Parking right near the trail to the lighthouse is very limited, but there are other spots in [the area](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Marin+Headlands+Visitors+Center/@37.8186644,-122.5340807,990m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x808585ede8288d71:0x75acd2c402940df5!8m2!3d37.830888!4d-122.5246681).

Comment: Too add to this. I ended up going there in July on a Saturday, and it was an overloaded zoo. It was very hard to find parking remotely close, and the roads were bumper to bumper, and the sidewalks butt to butt.

Comment: Thanks for the update @ScottF. A weekend during high tourist season does indeed sound like a busy time.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I've only done this by bike. I've rented a bike a few times in San Francisco, crossed the bridge and rode up the hill. There are two main parking areas (I believe!) and in the times I've been it would seem likely that you'd be able to park, perhaps if you have to wait a bit for someone to leave after doing a bit of sightseeing. Also, you can park in places on the road up the hill but you might have to walk a bit.

You do get a nice view of the bridge from the top of the hill providing the fog hasn't descended.

[image]

[Official information](http://www.parksconservancy.org/visit/park-sites/kirby-cove.html) including a view you might see:

[image]

Some information also available on a [tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g60713-i30-k5856321-My_hiking_plan_Sausalito_to_Kirby_Cove-San_Francisco_California.html) thread.

Comment: +1 Important point about the fog. If you're interested in views, try to plan your visit around the fog. The [forecast map](http://weather.sfgate.com/auto/sfgate/geo/fogmap/index.html?query=fogmap) is at least marginally useful, but as a general rule during summer, if you head out there as the morning fog burns off (if the morning fog every burns off), you'll get at least some time before it comes back in the afternoon or evening. Or stick around and the views might be more interesting as the fog comes in (or you might see nothing).